# string to Boolean expression is not working c++

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-variant, boost-phoenix

I have a following code to evaluate a Boolean string based on an string input.

The code supposed to work like this:

```
Boolean string: "((0|1)&3);"

Sting input: "101"
```

how's it working? each character in the input string is supposed to be substituted by corresponding character in Boolean string.

for example:

- 1 in the input string by 0 in Boolean string
- 0 in the input string by 1 in Boolean string
- 1 in the input string by 3 in Boolean string

I know it is confusing, My problem is that the code was used to work for many cases, but I don't understand why it is not working for above example.

I added the live version for editing [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61028725e5c45189).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>


namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

struct op_or  {};
struct op_and {};
struct op_not {};

typedef std::string var; 
template <typename tag> struct binop;
template <typename tag> struct unop;

typedef boost::variant<var, 
        boost::recursive_wrapper<unop <op_not> >, 
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and> >,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or> >
        > expr;

template <typename tag> struct binop
{
    explicit binop(const expr& l, const expr& r) : oper1(l), oper2(r) { }
    expr oper1, oper2;
};

template <typename tag> struct unop
{
    explicit unop(const expr& o) : oper1(o) { }
    expr oper1;
};

struct eval2 : boost::static_visitor<bool> 
{
    eval2(const std::string& pk): pkey(pk) { iter = 0; }

    //
    bool operator()(const var& v) const 
    { 
      std:: cout << "**** " << v << "\titer: " << iter << std::endl;
      iter ++;
      return boost::lexical_cast<bool>(pkey[iter-1]); 
    }

    bool operator()(const binop<op_and>& b) const
    {
        return recurse(b.oper1) && recurse(b.oper2);
    }
    bool operator()(const binop<op_or>& b) const
    {
        return recurse(b.oper1) || recurse(b.oper2);
    }
    bool operator()(const unop<op_not>& u) const
    {
        return !recurse(u.oper1);
    } 

    private:
    mutable int iter;
    const std::string pkey;
    template<typename T>
        bool recurse(T const& v) const 
        { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v); }
};

struct printer : boost::static_visitor<void> 
{
    printer(std::ostream& os) : _os(os) {}
    std::ostream& _os;

    //
    void operator()(const var& v) const { _os << v; }

    void operator()(const binop<op_and>& b) const { print(" & ", b.oper1, b.oper2); }
    void operator()(const binop<op_or >& b) const { print(" | ", b.oper1, b.oper2); }

    void print(const std::string& op, const expr& l, const expr& r) const
    {
        _os << "(";
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, l);
        _os << op;
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, r);
        _os << ")";
    }

    void operator()(const unop<op_not>& u) const
    {
        _os << "(";
        _os << "!";
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, u.oper1);
        _os << ")";
    } 
};

bool evaluate2(const expr& e, const std::string s) 
{ 
  return boost::apply_visitor(eval2(s), e); 
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const expr& e) 
{ boost::apply_visitor(printer(os), e); return os; }

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, expr(), Skipper>
{
        parser() : parser::base_type(expr_)
        {
            using namespace qi;

            expr_  = or_.alias();

            or_  = (and_ >> '|'  >> or_ ) [ qi::_val = phx::construct<binop<op_or > >(qi::_1, qi::_2) ] | and_   [ qi::_val = qi::_1 ];
            and_ = (not_ >> '&' >> and_)  [ qi::_val = phx::construct<binop<op_and> >(qi::_1, qi::_2) ] | not_   [ qi::_val = qi::_1 ];
            not_ = ('!' > simple       )  [ qi::_val = phx::construct<unop <op_not> >(qi::_1)     ] | simple [ qi::_val = qi::_1 ];

            simple = (('(' > expr_ > ')') | var_);
            var_ = qi::lexeme[ +(alpha|digit) ];

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expr_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(or_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(and_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(not_);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(simple);
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(var_);
        }

        private:
        qi::rule<It, var() , Skipper> var_;
        qi::rule<It, expr(), Skipper> not_, and_, or_, simple, expr_; 
};

bool string2BooleanExe(std::string bStatement, std::string bKey)
{
  typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
  It f(bStatement.begin()), l(bStatement.end());
  parser<It> p;
  try
  {
      expr result;
      bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,p > ';',qi::space,result);
      if (!ok)
      std::cerr << "invalid input\n";
      else
      {
      std::cout << "result:\t" << result << "\n";
      bool returnResult = evaluate2(result, bKey);
      std::cout << "evaluated:\t" << returnResult << "\n";
      return returnResult;
      }

  } catch (const qi::expectation_failure<It>& e)
  {
      std::cerr << "expectation_failure at '" << std::string(e.first, e.last) << "'\n";
  }

  if (f!=l) std::cerr << "unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
  return false;
}

int main()
{
    bool res = string2BooleanExe("((0|1)&3);", "101");
    std::cout << "res: " << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please note I can only use C++03.

Comment: This is pretty confusing. You've somehow mixed up string iteration and expression evaluation. This would work much better if you got rid of `iter` and instead made use of `v`.

Comment: ^ what @melpomene said. I'm showing a sample in a few minutes

Comment: Here's a simpler example that also fails: `string2BooleanExe("0&0;", "10")`

Comment: @melpomene it does not fail for string2BooleanExe("0&0;", "10") = 0

Comment: @H'H it makes more sense to expect `"0&0;"` to substitute true both times `0` is used. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want variables. And they are implicit.
And you denote them with integers in the expression. Yes, that's confusing, but why not, I guess.

The grammar suggests that variables could be any length of alphanumeric characters, though. Let's do this, and fix the sample to be:

```
bool res = string2BooleanExe("((a|b)&c);", {
        { "a", true }, { "b", false }, { "c", true } }); // was: 101
```

Now in your implementation there are two big problems:

1. you are using names `0`, `1`, `2` for the placeholders in the source expression but these are ignored (this means that `((0|1)&2)` is functionally equivalent to `((1|2)&0)`... I doubt that's what anyone wanted)
2. your `eval2`¹ visitor is stateful. You need to pass and use it by reference if you're going to retain state. Alternatively, make sure your copy constructor actually copies the value of `iter`

Here's my take on things, using

```
typedef std::map<std::string, bool> VarMap;
```

Let's use it in the `evaluator` visitor:

```
struct evaluator : boost::static_visitor<bool> 
{
    evaluator(VarMap const& pk) : pk(pk) { }

    bool operator()(const var& v) const { return pk.at(v); }
    bool operator()(const binop<op_and>& b) const { return recurse(b.oper1) && recurse(b.oper2); }
    bool operator()(const binop<op_or>&  b) const { return recurse(b.oper1) || recurse(b.oper2); }
    bool operator()(const unop<op_not>&  u) const { return !recurse(u.oper1); }

  private:
    template<typename T> bool recurse(T const& v) const { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v); }
    const VarMap pk;
};
```

Splitting the `evaluate` and `parse` functions:

```
static const parser<std::string::const_iterator> s_parser_instance;
expr parse(std::string const& bStatement) {
    std::string::const_iterator f = bStatement.begin(), l = bStatement.end();

    expr parsed;
    qi::parse(f, l, s_parser_instance, parsed);

    return parsed;
}

bool evaluate(expr const& e, VarMap const& vars) {
    return boost::apply_visitor(evaluator(vars), e); 
}
```

Now let's see the full demo

## Full Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/009c1cf3ecd42131)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp>

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

typedef std::map<std::string, bool> VarMap;

struct op_or  {};
struct op_and {};
struct op_not {};

typedef std::string var; 
template <typename tag> struct binop;
template <typename tag> struct unop;

typedef boost::variant<var, 
        boost::recursive_wrapper<unop <op_not> >, 
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_and> >,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<binop<op_or> >
    > expr;

template <typename tag> struct binop {
    explicit binop(const expr& l, const expr& r) : oper1(l), oper2(r) { }
    expr oper1, oper2;
};

template <typename tag> struct unop {
    explicit unop(const expr& o) : oper1(o) { }
    expr oper1;
};

struct evaluator : boost::static_visitor<bool> 
{
    evaluator(VarMap const& pk) : pk(pk) { }

    bool operator()(const var& v) const { return pk.at(v); }
    bool operator()(const binop<op_and>& b) const { return recurse(b.oper1) && recurse(b.oper2); }
    bool operator()(const binop<op_or>&  b) const { return recurse(b.oper1) || recurse(b.oper2); }
    bool operator()(const unop<op_not>&  u) const { return !recurse(u.oper1); }

  private:
    template<typename T> bool recurse(T const& v) const { return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v); }
    const VarMap pk;
};

struct printer : boost::static_visitor<void> 
{
    printer(std::ostream& os) : _os(os) {}
    std::ostream& _os;

    //
    void operator()(const var& v) const { _os << v; }

    void operator()(const binop<op_and>& b) const { print(" & ", b.oper1, b.oper2); }
    void operator()(const binop<op_or >& b) const { print(" | ", b.oper1, b.oper2); }

    void print(const std::string& op, const expr& l, const expr& r) const
    {
        _os << "(";
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, l);
        _os << op;
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, r);
        _os << ")";
    }

    void operator()(const unop<op_not>& u) const
    {
        _os << "(";
        _os << "!";
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, u.oper1);
        _os << ")";
    } 
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const expr& e) 
{ boost::apply_visitor(printer(os), e); return os; }

template <typename It>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, expr()>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start  = skip(space) [expr_ > ';' > eoi];

        expr_  = or_.alias();
        or_    = (and_ >> '|'  >> or_ ) [ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_or > >(_1, _2) ] | and_   [ _val = _1 ];
        and_   = (not_ >> '&' >> and_)  [ _val = phx::construct<binop<op_and> >(_1, _2) ] | not_   [ _val = _1 ];
        not_   = ('!' > simple       )  [ _val = phx::construct<unop <op_not> >(_1) ]     | simple [ _val = _1 ];

        simple = ('(' > expr_ > ')') | var_;
        var_   = lexeme[ +(alpha|digit) ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((expr_) (or_) (and_) (not_) (simple) (var_));
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, expr()> start;
    qi::rule<It, var() , qi::space_type> var_;
    qi::rule<It, expr(), qi::space_type> not_, and_, or_, simple, expr_; 
};

static const parser<std::string::const_iterator> s_parser_instance;
expr parse(std::string const& bStatement) {
    std::string::const_iterator f = bStatement.begin(), l = bStatement.end();

    expr parsed;
    qi::parse(f, l, s_parser_instance, parsed);

    return parsed;
}

bool evaluate(expr const& e, VarMap const& vars) {
    return boost::apply_visitor(evaluator(vars), e); 
}

void test(std::string const& expression, VarMap const& vars, bool expected) {
    try {
        std::cout << "'" << expression << "'";

        expr parsed = parse(expression);
        std::cout << " -> " << parsed;

        bool actual = evaluate(parsed, vars);
        std::cout 
            << " - evaluates to " << std::boolalpha << actual
            << (expected == actual? " Correct." : " INCORRECT!!!")
            << "\n";

    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << " EXCEPTION(" << e.what() << ")\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    VarMap vars;
    vars["a"] = true;
    vars["b"] = false;
    vars["c"] = true;

    test("a;", vars, true);
    test("b;", vars, false);
    test("c;", vars, true);

    test("((a|b)&c);", vars, true);

    vars["c"] = false;
    test("((a|b)&c);", vars, false);

    // let's use an undefined variable - should throw
    test("((z|y)&x);", vars, false|true);

    // you CAN still use confusing numeric placeholders:
    vars["0"] = true;
    vars["1"] = false;
    vars["2"] = true;
    test("((0|1)&2);", vars, true);
    test("((2|0)&1);", vars, false);
    test("((1|0)&2);", vars, true);

    // note you can also have "special variables"; no need for single-letter names
    vars["TRUE"] = true;
    vars["FALSE"] = false;
    test("TRUE | FALSE;", vars, true);
    test("TRUE & FALSE;", vars, false);
}
```

Prints:

```
'a;' -> a - evaluates to true Correct.
'b;' -> b - evaluates to false Correct.
'c;' -> c - evaluates to true Correct.
'((a|b)&c);' -> ((a | b) & c) - evaluates to true Correct.
'((a|b)&c);' -> ((a | b) & c) - evaluates to false Correct.
'((z|y)&x);' -> ((z | y) & x) EXCEPTION(map::at)
'((0|1)&2);' -> ((0 | 1) & 2) - evaluates to true Correct.
'((2|0)&1);' -> ((2 | 0) & 1) - evaluates to false Correct.
'((1|0)&2);' -> ((1 | 0) & 2) - evaluates to true Correct.
'TRUE | FALSE;' -> (TRUE | FALSE) - evaluates to true Correct.
'TRUE & FALSE;' -> (TRUE & FALSE) - evaluates to false Correct.
```

---

¹ FIX BAD NAMING. Also, single-responsibility. Make a `parse` function and an `evaluate` function. Put `';'` and the skipper inside the grammar. Check for `qi::eoi` inside the grammar. Propagate exceptions instead of doing magic console output inside your `parse/evaluate` function.